# Determine the limit of $\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^\frac{1}{i}$ as ${n \to \infty}$ .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How should I proceed? Should I count the sum upto infinity first and then proceed with the limit? Then again I can't even find the sum. Any help

Comment: You should start at $i=1$

Comment: Yes. My mistake

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{\log(n)}{n} \to 0$ so $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n$ increases

Comment: That'd be the last term of the series. What about the other terms divided by n?

Comment: I know the limit is $1$ but can't prove it in words.. or it does lie in $(1,2)$ that is seen from bounding the numerator

Comment: Hey @Henry , can you please solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{a_n\} \to a$ then $\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_n} {n} \to a$. Apply this with $a_n =n^{1/n}$ (and $a=1$).

Comment: Is that a rule? That'd mean sum of a series of n terms = n times the n-th term

Comment: These are limits, so it is not saying "sum of a series of $n$ terms = $n$ times the $n$-th term" (that would only be true if all the terms were the same, and they are not, but enough are close to being constant).  It means that the limit of the average is the limit of the individual terms (if that exists).

Comment: I got it. Thanks. This is actually Cauchy's first theorem on limits.